# Targeting different image size in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

So I know WordPress uploads different image sizes every time you upload an image.

So for example I upload an image called `background_main.jpg` and in my uploads folder 'll have :

```
background_main-1024x512.jpg
background_main-150x150.jpg
background_main-300x150.jpg
background_main-768x384.jpg
```

So currently to pull out an image I handle this like:

```
$classImg  = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($key->ID) );
```

Then I can spit it out by just using `$classImg`.

How can I pull out the same image but a smaller size for instance the 150x150 image or the 300x300 image?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at API, there is a function:

[wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large' );](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/)

'large' can be:

- large
- medium
- full
- thumbnail
- array ( n, m ) where n and m are pixels
- xyz where 'xyz' is custom defined size

Comment: The size argument can also be custom defined sizes if those exist.

Comment: @ksno i've tried adding this in however doesn't seem to be working. I write the `$classImg` into the DOM and it still reads the old image path and never changes to `background_main-300x150.jpg` image path or whatever size I pass it through

Comment: Are you using the function he refers to or the existing one in your code?

Comment: Brilliant that works! FYI to whom reading this when you use `wp_get_attachment_image_src();` you get back an array, which I didn't notice at first. Thanks @SimonPollard and @ksno :)

Comment: Thats why function was linked.